# How do I maintain integers from a JSON file in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a JSON file named `questions.json` that reads as follows:

```json
{
    "0" : {
        "Question" : "Simply sumbit the data in 'Get-Data' for this question",
        "Data" : "PowerShell is fun",
        "Answer" : "PowerShell is fun"
    },
    "1" : {
        "Question" : "Submit the sum of Get-Data + 5.",
        "Data" : 7,
        "Answer" : 13
    }
}
```

When I do to convert it to a PSCustomObject with:

```powershell
$a = Get-Content -Raw -Path questions.json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

It turns the integers at `($a.1).Data` and `($a.1).Answer` into strings.

```powershell
PS C:\> $a


0                                                                                                                    1
-                                                                                                                    -
@{Question=Simply sumbit the data in 'Get-Data' for this question; Data=PowerShell is fun; Answer=PowerShell is fun} @{Question=Submit the sum of Get-Data + 5.; D...
```

```powershell
PS C:\> $a.1


Question                        Data Answer
--------                        ---- ------
Submit the sum of Get-Data + 5. 7    13
```

```powershell
PS C:\> ($a.1).Data | gm

   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()
CompareTo        Method                int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(string strB), int IComparable.CompareTo(System.Object obj), int IComparab... 
Contains         Method                bool Contains(string value)
CopyTo           Method                void CopyTo(int sourceIndex, char[] destination, int destinationIndex, int count)
EndsWith         Method                bool EndsWith(string value), bool EndsWith(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool EndsWith(string valu... 
Equals           Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(string value), bool Equals(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType... 
GetEnumerator    Method                System.CharEnumerator GetEnumerator(), System.Collections.IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(), System.Collections.Gener... 
GetHashCode      Method                int GetHashCode()
GetType          Method                type GetType()
GetTypeCode      Method                System.TypeCode GetTypeCode(), System.TypeCode IConvertible.GetTypeCode()
IndexOf          Method                int IndexOf(char value), int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int IndexOf(string value), int IndexOf(string value, int ... 
IndexOfAny       Method                int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex, in... 
Insert           Method                string Insert(int startIndex, string value)
IsNormalized     Method                bool IsNormalized(), bool IsNormalized(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizationForm)
LastIndexOf      Method                int LastIndexOf(char value), int LastIndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int LastIndexOf(string value), int LastIndexOf(st...
LastIndexOfAny   Method                int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int st... 
Normalize        Method                string Normalize(), string Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizationForm)
PadLeft          Method                string PadLeft(int totalWidth), string PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
PadRight         Method                string PadRight(int totalWidth), string PadRight(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
Remove           Method                string Remove(int startIndex, int count), string Remove(int startIndex)
Replace          Method                string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar), string Replace(string oldValue, string newValue)
Split            Method                string[] Split(Params char[] separator), string[] Split(char[] separator, int count), string[] Split(char[] separator, Syst... 
StartsWith       Method                bool StartsWith(string value), bool StartsWith(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool StartsWith(strin... 
Substring        Method                string Substring(int startIndex), string Substring(int startIndex, int length)
ToBoolean        Method                bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToByte           Method                byte IConvertible.ToByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToChar           Method                char IConvertible.ToChar(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToCharArray      Method                char[] ToCharArray(), char[] ToCharArray(int startIndex, int length)
ToDateTime       Method                datetime IConvertible.ToDateTime(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToDecimal        Method                decimal IConvertible.ToDecimal(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToDouble         Method                double IConvertible.ToDouble(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToInt16          Method                int16 IConvertible.ToInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToInt32          Method                int IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToInt64          Method                long IConvertible.ToInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToLower          Method                string ToLower(), string ToLower(cultureinfo culture)
ToLowerInvariant Method                string ToLowerInvariant()
ToSByte          Method                sbyte IConvertible.ToSByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToSingle         Method                float IConvertible.ToSingle(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToString         Method                string ToString(), string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider), string IConvertible.ToString(System.IFormatProvider pr... 
ToType           Method                System.Object IConvertible.ToType(type conversionType, System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUInt16         Method                uint16 IConvertible.ToUInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUInt32         Method                uint32 IConvertible.ToUInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUInt64         Method                uint64 IConvertible.ToUInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUpper          Method                string ToUpper(), string ToUpper(cultureinfo culture)
ToUpperInvariant Method                string ToUpperInvariant()
Trim             Method                string Trim(Params char[] trimChars), string Trim()
TrimEnd          Method                string TrimEnd(Params char[] trimChars)
TrimStart        Method                string TrimStart(Params char[] trimChars)
Chars            ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}
Length           Property              int Length {get;}
```

How to I maintain their type when converting into a PowerShell usable object?

The script is supposed to be fluid, so I cannot just go through and change each object type individually.

Comment: They're integers for me in powershell 5.1.

Comment: This would suggest a bug, therefore it is important to add the PowerShell version and operating system **to the question**.

Comment: Tested (from a file) under PowerShell 7.0.0 / Windows 10 and it works fine for me too (`($a.1).Answer.GetType().FullName` returns `System.Int64`)

Answer (score 1):

[`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7) should handle converting the correct types when deserializing into a `PSCustomObject`, as shown below:

```
$a = Get-Content -Path .\questions.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

($a.0).Data.GetType().FullName
# System.String

($a.0).Answer.GetType().FullName
# System.String

($a.1).Data.GetType().FullName
# System.Int64

($a.1).Answer.GetType().FullName
# System.Int64
```

We could also test this quickly with a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7#here-strings):

```
$json = @"
    {
        "0" : {
            "Question" : "Simply sumbit the data in 'Get-Data' for this question",
            "Data" : "PowerShell is fun",
            "Answer" : "PowerShell is fun"
        },
        "1" : {
            "Question" : "Submit the sum of Get-Data + 5.",
            "Data" : 7,
            "Answer" : 13
        }
    }
"@

$a = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

($a.0).Data.GetType().FullName
# System.String

($a.0).Answer.GetType().FullName
# System.String

($a.1).Data.GetType().FullName
# System.Int64

($a.1).Answer.GetType().FullName
# System.Int64
```